# Handle before_filter with overridden functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def func
  end
end

class BaseController < ApplicationController
  def func(a)
  end
end

class MyController < BaseController
  before_filter :func # I want this to call ApplicationController::func
end
```

In this case, the BaseController::func is called. How do I call ApplicationController's one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a good way to hack `before_filter` itself to make it work. But I think this alternative might just do what you are looking for.

Try this.

```
class MyController < BaseController
  before_filter :application_func

  private
    def application_func
      ApplicationController.func
    end
end
```